# Prove that the Zariski space $\text{Zar} \space (K,A)$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, compactness, proof-explanation

I posted part of the proof from Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory. I got stuck in the last sentence where it says "Hence the intersection of all the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ is the same thing as the intersection of the sets of the form $U(x)^c$ belonging to $\mathcal{A}$. I am not sure why this is true...

**Note**: $U(x_1, ... , x_n) := \text{Zar} \space (K, A[x_1, ... , x_n])$, where $A$ is a subring of the field $K$.

[image] 
[image]

I'm not sure why the last sentence is true and would appreciate any kind of help...

Comment: By property $\alpha$?

Comment: @Slade So suppose we have only two elements in $\mathcal{A}$, namely $F = U(x_1, x_2)^c \cap U(x_3)^c$ and $G = U(x_2, x_3)^c \cap U(x_4, x_6)^c$. By property $\beta$, suppose we have $U(x_2)^c, U(x_3)^c, U(x_4)^c \in \mathcal{A}$. Then how is the intersection of $F$ and $G$ equal to the intersection of $U(x_2)^c, U(x_3)^c$, and  $U(x_4)^c$? We might have a valuation ring $R$ not containing $A[x_2] \cup A[x_3] \cup A[x_4]$ meaning that $R \in U(x_2)^c \cap U(x_3)^c \cap U(x_4)^c$. But $R$ may contain $x_6$ which implies that $R \not\in F \cap G$. So what does property $\alpha$ tell us?

Comment: You say that $\mathcal{A}$ contains only two elements, but then you calculate several other elements in it.  It is not possible that $\mathcal{A}$ contains only $F$ and $G$.

Comment: @Slade Ok, I guess I made a mistake...$U(x_2)^c$, $U(x_3)^c$, $U(x_4)^c$ are also contained in $\mathcal{A}$. However, that doesn't answer my question. We can see (obviously), that the intersection of all elements in $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in the intersection of the sets of the form $U(x)^c$ belonging to $\mathcal{A}$. But the proof says that the converse also holds: if we have an element $R$ in $U(x_2)^c \cap U(x_3)^c \cap U(x_4)^c$, then $R$ must be contained in the intersection of **all** elements of $\mathcal{A}$. How is that true? What if $R$ contains $x_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

I don’t perfectly understand the algebraic constructions from the proof, but it is not necessary, because
its topological constructions are clear. :-) In fact, by [Alexander subbase theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Alexander_subbase_theorem), a space $X$ is compact iff it has a subbase $\mathcal B$ that that each cover of $X$ by elements of $\mathcal B$ has a finite subcover.

So, let $F\in\mathcal A$. Then $F^c=\bigcup_\lambda U_\lambda$ for some family $U_\lambda$ of (canonical?) open sets, and hence $F=\bigcap_\lambda U^c_\lambda$. By Property $\gamma$, $ U^c_\lambda\in\mathcal A$ for each $\lambda$. Moreover, $U^c_\lambda=U(x_1,\dots,x_n)^c=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U(x_i)^c$ for some $x_1,\dots, x_n$. By Property $\beta$ (which follows from the maximality of the family $\mathcal A$), one of the $U(x_i)^c$ must belong to $\mathcal A$.  Denote this set $U(x_i)^c$ as $G_\lambda$. Then $F=\bigcap_\lambda U^c_\lambda\supset \bigcap_\lambda G_\lambda$. Therefore each set $F\in\mathcal A$ contains an intersection ($\bigcap_\lambda G_\lambda$) of the sets of the form $U(x)^c$  belonging to $\mathcal A$.